# Separate Table vs Extra Columns in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am wondering about best practices in database design with Hibernate.

I have a User entity that is going to have **a lot** of different settings. For each set of settings, I have to either add them as extra columns in the User table or create a separate entity and connect them with a @OneToOne relationship. It is my understanding that @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationships should generally take place in separate tables because you should not have columns that are optional.

But it is kind of unclear for @OneToOne relationships. I think there is a case for using @OneToOne because ORMs will select all single attributes by default and having a lot of columns will slow down that process.

An example of what I am talking about can be illustrated by

```
@Entity
public class User{

@OneToOne
private ForumSettings forumSettings;

@OneToOne
private AccountSettings accountSettings;

@OneToOne
private SecuritySettings securitySettings;

}
```

vs

```
@Entity
public class User{

@Column
private boolean showNSFWContent; //Forum Setting

@Column 
private int numberOfCommentsPerPage; //Forum Setting

@Column
private boolean subscribedToNewsLetter; //Account Setting

@Column
private boolean isAccountBanned; //Account Setting

@Column 
private boolean isTwoFactorAuthenticationEnabled; //Security Setting

@Column
private boolean alertForSuspiciousLogin; //Security Setting

}
```

The above is a simple example to show the concept, but in practice there would be many more columns in the 2nd portion.

I know that this might be opinion based, but I am hoping someone could share the pros/cons of both choices.

Thank you very much

Comment: There are also [`@Embedded`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables) properties.

Comment: Why don't you make base `Settings` class and then just add property `type` to `Settings` class? Then association between `User` and `Settings` could be `OneToMany`. In general this is more database design question, rather than implementation (jpa, hibernate). What you are asking is how to normalize data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is in general about Data normalization. Normalization is itself  extensive field of study and basically is a way of structuring database tables avoiding redundancy and making sure that updates don’t introduce anomalies.

And first rule of normalization says a table shall contain no repeating groups. In your case it does.

**SOLUTION 1 : Store UserSettings as Entity as map as OneToMany relationship**

```
    @Entity
    public class User

    @OneToMany
    private List<UserSettings> userSettings;
```

And then you can query for particular `setting` type by joining `User` and `UserSettings` entities.

For example (JPQL)

```
  SELECT user u 
  JOIN u.settings us
  WHERE us.settings_type = 'account_settings' 
        and us.settings_value = 'secure' // or any other logic
```

Advantage of this approach is that `UserSettings` will have it is own persistence identity and can be queried by it's own. It it is not dependent on parent.
For example :

```
 SELECT q from Query q where ...
```

---

**Solution 2 : Store settings in a collection of basic elements**

You can store User Settings in the collection (Each user will have it's own set of settings)

```
   @Entity
        public class User {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private long id;

            private String name;

            ...

            @ElementCollection
            @CollectionTable(name="USER_SETTINGS")
            @MapKeyColumn(name="SETTINGS_TYPE")
            @Column(name="SETTINGS_VALUE")
            Map<String, Boolean> userSettings = new HashMap<>();
```

`UserSettings` collection will be stored in a separate table with `foreign key` to `User` table. `UserSettings` does not have it is own persistence ID, is dependent on `User` entity and can be queried only through it is parent ('User')

---

**Solution 3: Store User Settings as Embedded type**

Embedded type is not an entity, it does not have it is own persistence ID and is  depends on parent type, stored as part of parent record in database (in `User` table)

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    ...

    @Embedded
    private UserSettings userSettings;
```

UserSettings is in separate class, but stored in `User` table.

```
@Embeddable
public class UserSettings {

    private List<String> securitySettings;  // or any other collection type

    private List<Boolean> forumSettings;
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. The number of columns each "UserSettings" has is a fixed number. But it is possible account settings has 4 attributes, security settings has 3 attributes, forum settings has 7 attributes...etc

Comment: Oh actually I think I misinterpreted your answer. I think you meant "UserSetting" (not plural) and each UserSetting is a key/value pair of the type of setting and its value. But this would force all values to be of the same type such as String

Comment: UserSettings shall have only one column - `attribute` and each attribute will be separate row (if you have 3 to 7 attributes only)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the options! I'm going to have to explore them carefully these next few days.